# What is the difference between &str and &String

Tags: rust

I'm walking through Microsoft's Rust tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/rust-memory-management/4-exercise-lifetimes), which is about

> implement the `copy_and_return` function so that it returns a reference
> to the value inserted in the vector

Solution is given [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a687fa389ffc14dedd80c0320e7ae8c9), but it's different from mine in that it used &String as return type while I used &str.

```rust
// standard solution
fn copy_and_return<'a>(vector: &'a mut Vec<String>, value: &'a str) -> &'a String {
    vector.push(String::from(value));
    vector.get(vector.len() - 1).unwrap()
}
```

```
// my solution
fn copy_and_return<'a>(vector: &'a mut Vec<String>, value: &'a str) -> &'a str {
    vector.push(String::from(value));
    return value; // simply return value
}

fn main() {
    let name1 = "Joe";
    let name2 = "Chris";
    let name3 = "Anne";

    let mut names = Vec::new();

    assert_eq!("Joe", copy_and_return(&mut names, &name1));
    assert_eq!("Chris", copy_and_return(&mut names, &name2));
    assert_eq!("Anne", copy_and_return(&mut names, &name3));

    assert_eq!(
        names,
        vec!["Joe".to_string(), "Chris".to_string(), "Anne".to_string()]
    )
}
```

In addition to the return type, another difference between mine and the standard solution is that I simply returned the parameter `value`, while the standard solution used complicated way `vector.get(vector.len() - 1).unwrap()`.

I'm wondering if there's anything wrong with my solution that the tutorial takes another way?

---

While @Masklinn provided a great answer to my question, it's a bit specific to the example I gave but not directly addressing the title `What is the difference between &str and &String`.
I found [this discussion](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-str/10177/3) to be quite informative:

> Basically a `String` wraps and manages a dynamically allocated str as backing storage.
> Since str cannot be resized, String will dynamically allocate/deallocate memory.
> A `&str` is thus a reference directly into the backing storage of the String, while &String is a reference to the “wrapper” object.
> Additionaly, &str can be used for substrings, i.e. they are slices. A &String references always the whole string.

[Chapter 4.3](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/ch04-03-slices.html) of the Rust book also helps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm wondering if there's anything wrong with my solution that the tutorial takes another way?

I don't think there's anything wrong per se, yours might even match the function name better depending how its interpreted: are you supposed to copy and return the original, or copy and return the copy? Yours is the first pick, theirs is the second.

It's made irrelevant by the lifetimes, but this does make a difference to program behaviour: in the "official" solution, the result is a reference to the value inserted into the `Vec`, meaning it will be "live" for as long as the vector is (at least assuming the vector is not otherwise modified).

You can see the difference if you replace `value: &'a str` by `value: &'_ str` (aka "a lifetime you don't care about but is different from `'a`): the official solution still compiles, yours does not.

Though note that the official could just as well return `&'a str` regardless:

```rust
fn copy_and_return<'a>(vector: &'a mut Vec<String>, value: &'_ str) -> &'a str {
    vector.push(String::from(value));
    vector.get(vector.len() - 1).unwrap()
}
```

The official solution is hardly great through e.g.

```rust
vector.get(vector.len() - 1)
```

is a complicated way of writing

```rust
vector.last()
```

but it might be that they just don't want to overwhelm the reader with advanced APIs or something, I could not say.

Comment: If you don't care about the lifetime of `value`, it's easiest to simply omit the lifetime, rather than specifying `'_`.